# How to share an object between test methods?

Tags: apex, unit-test, test-setup

I get `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object` when I try to do the following:

```
@isTest
private class MyControllerTest {
    static MyController controller;

    @testSetup static void setup () {
        controller = new MyController();
    }

    @isTest static void test_method_one () {
        controller.myStringProperty = 'Something';
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to share initialised variables between \@testSetup and \@isTest methods (other than querying for inserted records).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bottom line is that you can't. As explained in the product management comment to this [Remember static variables set during testSetup annotated methods](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dj51AAC) idea:

> We intentionally clear out static variables between each test method. 
>   If we did not, each test would cease to be an independent trial. You
>   could modify the static in one test method, which would make the order
>   in which tests operate relevant to the results.  This is precisely
>   what you don't want - data dependent tests.
>
> If you want information that is common to all tests, it can be
>   inserted in the test setup method and queried in each test method. 
>   The idea here is not to reduce the number of SOQL queries, it is to
>   reduce the amount of data being inserted into the system.  If you
>   insert 1000 records in test setup, run fifteen test methods, and you
>   run a query 15 times to get the 1000 records each time, that's still
>   less expensive (and faster) than inserting 1000 records 15 times.

However, you can share code between test methods. The pattern we most often use is an inner class that contains object setup methods that assign to fields and also assert methods. That allows the code to be re-used, although it obviously means that the objects are re-created per test.