# StackTrace - External Entry point

Tags: unit-test, test-setup

When I run my test class by using a method marked with @testSetup annotation, I get into nullPointer exception and the stack trace is shown as - "External Entry Point". Suprisingly when I move the same data creation code to the individual testMethods thigs work smoothly. Have anybody run into this kind of situation. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks

Comment: Please include code to repro.

Comment: This question/answer may be relevant to your problem [How to share an object between test methods?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113739/how-to-share-an-object-between-test-methods).